# Adding RDF model from lastfm.rdfize.com

Tags: java, rdf, jena, last.fm

I am programming in Java, trying to make a simple RDF Store using Jena library and lastfm.rdfize.com website.

I'm getting into the following problem:
the lastfm.rdfize.com produces an rdf, for example in Turtle on the request like:
"http://lastfm.rdfize.com/?username=&eventID=&artistName="+artistName+"&venueID=&output=turtle"

I make a request and take the contents of the resulting web page.
If I print them - they seem like a decent RDF to me.

However, I can't add them to the model.

I tried creating a file, writing the String(which is the HTML content) to this file(which also seems okay) and reading it to the model like that:

```
InputStream lastf = FileManager.get().open("lastfm.txt");
Model temp=null;
temp=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
temp.read(lastf,null,"Turtle");
```

However, at this point I get the following error message:

(ErrorHandlerLib.java:49) - [line: 22, col: 2 ] Unknown char:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work for me with a trivial RDF/Turtle like ...

```
@base <http://example.org/ns/> .                                                                                                                     
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<s1> <p1> <o1>;
<p2> "some typed literal"^^xsd:string;
<p2> "some non-typed literal";
<p4> 10 .
<o1> <label> "some label" .
```

It seems therefore that you have some format or charset error in your data file `lastfm.txt`.
I suggest to validate your file with an RDF validator, try with http://www.rdfabout.com/demo/validator/
With this validator you can test both RDF/XML and RDF/Turtle make sure you select the correct format for the type of RDF serialization you are working with.

Another option to validate your data could be the *raptor* tool from http://librdf.org 
but this one is a bit more sophisticated and you need to install it locally.

If the validators shouts with a charset error then you could change the charset you are using to read your data. Something like this should work ..

```
package t1;                        
import java.io.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

class test {
 public static void main (String[] args) { 
       InputStreamReader lastf = new 
          InputStreamReader(FileManager.get().open("lastfm.txt"),
                            Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

       Model temp=null;
       temp=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
       temp.read(lastf,null,"Turtle");
       System.out.println(temp.size());
       temp.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

All this should give you a guideline to spot the error (I hope) but If you don't spot it then post the data so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the problem was indeed in the charset. Once I explicitly stated to save the file in UTF-8, everything work good.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like charset trouble. Is the file in uTF-8 or something else?

Comment: Yes, it was the charset, had to explicitly make it in UTF-8